# how to get the same result with c.test() in a(c.test)?

Tags: javascript

how to get cccc result？

c is an obj with children property and method , I want to run other function with c.method, such as bellow , how can i let get the result as the same as c.test()?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function a(fn){
    fn();
}

function b(){
    alert('bbbb');
}

var c={
    name: 'cccc',
    test: function (){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

a(b);       // get 'bbbb';
a(c.test);  // get empty string, how can i get 'cccc'?

</script>
```

Comment: you can just use `c.name` instead of `this.name`

`this` in the function does not reference `c`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure that inside `c.test` the value of `this` is `c`. This is achievable with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
a(c.test.bind(c));
```

Note that `bind` is not available on IE 8 or earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the scope of this inside the function.

```
var c={
  name: 'cccc',
  test: function (){
      alert(c.name);
  }
}
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

`a(function (){c.test()})`